# Grub Legacy entries for Remix OS and Ubuntu

Tags: grub2, android, ubuntu-minimal, grub-legacy

I have a desktop running Remix OS and the only way it will boot correctly is to use legacy grub.  I have an install of Ubuntu Minimal in an adjacent partition but I can't figure out the correct grub entry to boot it. All help blogs point to booting with grub2 for Ubuntu but if I do that then Remix doesn't start. I'll supply any requested info and really need the help. Since Remix is Android, Super Grub Disk and boot-repair do not work. Ideally I'd want to chainload grub to grub2 or vice versa.